# ASP.Net Master Page not responding to Site.css Alterations

Tags: asp.net, css

Alterations to Site.css appears to be having no effect when debugging.

Comment: Have any effect when not debugging ? - pointless....

Answer (score -1):

Firefox was default browser for debug session. It was using its cached copy of Sites.css after the first debug run
Solution is to turn off Firefox history. It will then reload Sites.css each time

Comment: You can do the same by pressing `shift+f5`, or `shift+reload button` - and not change the default behavior.

Comment: Aristos Solution better. Hitting F5 is so ingrained with me. I didn't know / remember shift + f5